# Is there any way to configure hyperledger besu to mine blocks only when there are transactions?

Tags: private-blockchain, besu, ibft

I have been following this tutorial:
https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Tutorials/Private-Network/Create-IBFT-Network/

Everything works fine, however I can see that every 2 seconds new block is added even thou there is no transactions at that moment. Is there any way to configure network that uses IBFT 2.0 to mine blocks only when there are transactions...